# Extract ids from columns

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this

```
Anid|Mycfi2_180833_Genemark.11845_g     scer|maker-scaffold119_size133949-snap-gene-0.138-mRNA-2
Medi|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001  scer|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-6 
Scer|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001  Oryz|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-2
Usti|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001  Mfij|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-2
Usti|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001  Anid|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-2
Anid|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001  Medi|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-2
```

Actually there are several other columns in the same file. I would need to grep some of these ids for instance I want anything that starts with Anid, Usti, Medi, Oryz it does not matter if they are in column 1 or 2. but I want only the ids and not the full line.

I tried

```
  awk '/^Anid| / {print $1}' data
```

It does give me

```
  Anid|Mycfi2_180833_Genemark.11845_g
  Anid|Mycfi2_212664_estExt_fgenesh1_kg.C_120001
```

and to extract the same from second column I use

```
  awk '/^Anid| / {print $2}' data

 Anid|maker-scaffold69_size108554-augustus-gene-0.130-mRNA-2
```

Is there an efficient way to get all the ids starting with these 4 words from both column 1 and column 2 in a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `egrep -o`

```
egrep -o "\<(Anid|Usti|Medi|Oryz)\S*"
```

The `\<` implies that it must be the beginning of a word.  Notice that if you have two matches on the same line it will print two lines (but I'm assuming that's what you want anyway)

Comment: Thanks it works, is it possible to grep multiple patterns this way. This was part of my question "anything that starts with Anid, Usti, Medi, Oryz".

Comment: egrep -o "\<(Anid|Usti)\S*"...   I'll update the answer